# How to check weave router ip for k8s nodes?

Tags: networking, kubernetes, weave

Every k8s node have individual ip, which is router for all dockers running on it. Is there any way to check by api (k8s, weave, etc...) - ip's of others nodes?

I can run of course docker on every node and then check what's router ip there, or just connect to every node and check which ip is on weave device - but there must be simpler (api ;)) way to do that :-)

Comment: Hi, I work on Weave Net but I don't understand your question.  Is it the IP of the node (i.e. the machine) that you want, or some part of the Weave Net implementation?

Comment: i have 3 node k8s node. Between them there is a weave network - all dockers running on cluster are in the same l2 "weave" network. Default gateway for them is always on local weave instance - so traffic to internet is routed only through local machine. I would like to know every router'is ip (which is known inside weave network) for every node. Now - i can run on every machine a docker and check router's ip in it - but i would like to check it by api or something.

Comment: Hi @undefine, what exactly do you mean by "router's IP"? 
Could you maybe provide an example of what you want with some Linux commands and their output? This should hopefully clarify your requirement and allow us to reply to your question. Thanks!